# Network Efficiency: Send a String or a Integer?

Tags: c#, string, sockets, networking, integer

Lets say I want to send the number, 1, over the network and to my clients,
would it be better if I use a string rather than a 32-bit Integer?

Since I only have 1 character that I want to send, it would mean that I'm sending 1 byte over the network if I were to use a string right?

And if I were to use a 32-bit Integer for that it would mean that I'm sending 4 bytes of data over the network right?

Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere

Comment: If your number always fits on 1 character, why not send it as a byte?

Comment: sorry, the data that i want to sent isn't always 1 character

Comment: In that case, binary is generally more compact than a string to represent integers (as soon as they have more than 4 digits)

Comment: I can't help but think that this is a micro-optimization. The overhead and latency of sending *any* bytes (be it 1 or 4) over the network is huge. The only scenario I can imagine where this'd be useful is if you were talking about storing or transmitting millions or more such numbers at a time.

Comment: i'm currently writing a game server that'll be able to host thousands of clients simultaneously, and I want to squeeze every bit of performance as much as possible, is this optimization really that insignificant?

Comment: You have a real-world performance question. The only way to get an answer is **try it both ways and see what happens**. If you have two horses and you want to know which is faster, *race them*.

Comment: @CatsGalore if you're sending a network packet just to send this one number `1`, yes, I believe it is that insignificant, even in your scenario. But as Eric says, the only way to be sure is to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it would mean that I'm sending 1 byte over the network if I were to use a string right?

If you encode it as ASCII without termination and length information, yes.

Especially if you manage to magically avoid network overhead. 1 number is still a TCP packet, which is still an ethernet packet.